# Python: Dictionary variable within classes

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 'switch' statement using the dictionary method. I can do this without classes, but with classes I can't seem to make it work no matter what type of incantation I try.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import sys

def func1(var1):
    print("hi guy")
    return 0

Mycode = { 5:func1 }

indx1 = 5
var1 = 0
temp = Mycode[indx1]
temp(var1)
sys.exit()

The above code works.
The code below does not work

#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import sys

class Beef():

    def __init__(self):
        junk = 3

    def func1(self, var1):
        print("hi guy")
        return 0

    def find(self):
        self.Mycode = { 5:func1 }
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        indx1 = 5
        var1 = 0 
        temp = self.Mycode[indx1]
        errcode = temp(0)
        sys.exit()


hvfbeef = Beef()
hvfbeef.find()
```

I get the error "NameError: name 'func1' is not defined" , although upon other permutations I get other errors. 
I seems the I don't understand how the dictionary works within classes and functions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.Mycode = { 5:self.func1 }

                  ^^^^
```

It should be `self.`

Also,

```
temp = self.Mycode[indx1]

       ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank-you very much!